# Filtering data in a table - how to organize it correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I study the spring+Hibernate bundle there Is an entity:

```
public class PersonEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private City city;
    private Countrycountry;
...
}
```

I need to perform filtering. data in this table to display in the browser window. I was thinking of making an implementation in the service of the following methods:

```
.findByName(name);
.findByNameAndAge(name, age);
.findByNameAndAge(name, age, city);
.findByNameAndAge(name, city);
...
```

But it turns out that there are too many options for methods. How to make one universal method, i.e. something like a collection in which you can add as many parameters as you need. I started reading on this issue and got completely confused. Somewhere they write about @Filter, somewhere about Hibernate Search, there is also Spring Data Elasticsearch. Tell me the easiest and most relevant way to implement this. If there are links to real examples, I would be very grateful.

Dao:

```
public interface PersonDao extends GeneralDAO<PersonEntity>{
    public List<PersonEntity> searchName(String name);
    public List<PersonEntity> searchAllFields(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city);
}
```

GeneralDAO describes all standard methods such as get, save, etc. Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndAgeAndCity(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService implements PersonRepository {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    ...
    описание всех стандартных методов чтения-записи в БД

    @Override
    public List<PersonEntity> searchName(String name) {
        return productTypeRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonEntity> searchAllFields(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city) {
        return personRepository.findByNameAndAgeAndCity(
                name,
                age,
                city);
    }
}
```

In the ad and call controller:

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;
...

personService.searchAllFields(...);
```

The searchName method works fine, but searchAllFields doesn't. It always returns an empty list, even if I specify one name, the rest = null

I tried to change the method in the service:

```
List<PersonEntity> findByNameIsNullAndAgeIsNullAndCityIsNull
```

Spring responds with an error:
"Error creating bean with name personRepository. At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query".

Answer (score 1):

**searchAllFields** Method is returning an empty list because it contains findByNameAndAgeAndCity which means all the parameters are mandatory and the condition between them is **AND** so better change to **OR** (**findByNameOrAgeOrCity**) so that if you pass single value like name and rest = null then also you will get data and vice-versa.

Comment: No. In this case, the filter only works on one field. And I need it to work in all fields. Ignoring only the = null fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using `Criteria API` since you are using `Spring & Spring Data`, you can use JPA Specifications as a complete example see the following example:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
....
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
}
```

// Notice the the second extended interface **JpaSpecificationExecutor** ^

in service:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
....

public List<PersonEntity> list(PersonEntityFilter personFilter) {
    List<PersonEntity> filteredPersons = personsRepository.findAll
        (Specification.where(PersonEntitySpecs.findByFilters(personFilter)));
    return filteredPersons;
  }
```

`PersonEntityFilter` is the payload coming from your controller submitted by your clients or your UI and it is a simple class that groups all fields you want to filter by

```
public class PersonEntityFilter {
      private String name;
      private Integer age;
      private City city;

     // getters & setters
}
```

`PersonEntitySpecs` is where you put your specs (criteria query logic)

```
public class PersonEntitySpecs {

 public static Specification<PersonEntity> findByFilters(PersonEntityFilter personEntityFilter) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
      final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
      if (personEntityFilter.getName() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + personEntityFilter.getName() + "%")));
      }

      if (personEntityFilter.getAge() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("age"), personEntityFilter.getAge()));
      }

      if (personEntityFilter.getCity() != null) {
        Join<PersonEntity, CityEntity> personCityJoin = root.join("city");

        predicates.add(cb.equal(personCityJoin.get("id"), personEntityFilter.getCity().getId()));
      }

      return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
   }
}
```